# ansible collections - Collection level variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-collections

Is there a way to provide variables at collection level. So that all roles in this collection can access the variable?

*Example Usecase*: A collection with multiple roles for a company.
Many roles need a default network storage location.

**Possible workarounds**:

1. Having a role that all other roles in the collection depend upon that calls `set_fact`
2. Setting facts on the instances

Comment: Why `set_facts` ? A `default_vars_only` role added as a dependency with a single `vars/main.yml` file should do the trick. If you need those vars to be a bit more overridable, you can use `defaults/main.yml`.

Comment: You are right - that is even better. The nicest (and most explicit) way would be to have some collection - level variables.

Comment: Note that you can have a `vars` folder at top level of the `playbook` folder. That might suit your needs as well depending on your exact requirement:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/dev_guide/developing_collections.html#collection-structure

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, thanks. The problem is that there is no docs on the playbooks directory. It is not clear 1. if the vars are imported if one runs a playbook that is not in this collection 2. if it is intended like that (and it is not even clear how to run a playbook from the collection)

Comment: 1. files in the vars dir adjacent to a playbook are not imported automagically anyway. But the dir is added to the search path wihch eases writting like `vars_files: [a.yml, b.yml]` at play level or `[import_vars: {path: somefile.yml}]` at task level. Vars dir inside a playbook dir in a collection are no exception. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths 2. playbook in a collection can be run/included from any other location. I'm not sure they have anything particular. For anything automagic, go  with the role dependency IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Put your variables in playbooks/group_vars/all.yml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).